# How to get customerid inside custom block to display in frontend myaccount section?

Tags: magento2

How to get customer_id in block and pass data to phtml file and also pass custom data from our module as grid.
Here I'm getting null value when i was get customer_id in block file.

Answer (score 2):

Try below code to get **customer Id** or Other **customer data** from block to template(phtml) file

> app/code/YourCompanyName/YourModuleName/Block/YourCustomBlock.php

```
<?php
namespace YourCompanyName\YourModuleName\Block;
class YourCustomBlock extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_customerSession;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory $customerSession,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession->create();
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getLoggedinCustomerId() {
        if ($this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            return $this->_customerSession->getId();
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function getCustomerData() {
        if ($this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            return $this->_customerSession->getCustomerData();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

> Now, we can use the functions in our view (.phtml) file as follows.

```
<?php
    $customerId = $block->getLoggedinCustomerId();
    echo 'Customer Id: ' . $customerId;

    $customerData = $block->getCustomerData();
    if($customerData) {
        echo 'Customer Id: ' . $customerData->getId() . '<br/>';
        echo 'Customer Name: ' . $customerData->getName() . '<br/>';
        echo 'Customer Email: ' . $customerData->getEmail() . '<br/>';
        echo 'Customer Group Id: ' . $customerData->getGroupId() . '<br/>';
    }
```

> You can also get customer Id directly in your template(phtml) file
>   using below code

```
    <?php
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $customerSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
    if ($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
        echo 'Customer Id: ' . $customerSession->getCustomer()->getId() . '<br/>';
        echo 'Customer Name: ' . $customerSession->getCustomer()->getName() . '<br/>';
        echo 'Customer Email: ' . $customerSession->getCustomer()->getEmail() . '<br/>';
        echo 'Customer Group Id: ' .  $customerSession->getCustomer()->getGroupId() . '<br/>';
    }

?>
```

> NOTE: You only get customer id if customer logged in and customer
>   session initialized

Hope that above code help you. If need any further help Let me know..!

Comment: I have created a grid by using uicomponent  and i cannot know how to use it inside customer edit tab in magento2.